# Post Image To REST API in android

Tags: android, api, rest, android-asynctask

I want to send image to REST API in android.I have created an android app which simply make a request call to API and return response but know i have to post Image to REST API.

Here is my code.

```
    private class PostImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... data) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/JAXRS-FileUpload/rest/files/upload");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        }
    }
```

How can i make post request to post image to REST API.Here is rest api code.

```
@Path("/files")
public class JerseyFileUpload {
@POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ImageUrl responseMsg(){
    //do something
    }
```

Which media type should use to consume image.

Answer (score 2):

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
FileBody userPhoto = new FileBody(new File(path));
entity.addPart("file", userPhoto);

String url = UPDATE_PROFILE_URL;
HttpParams params1 = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(params1, false);

int timeOut = 2 * 60 * 1000;

HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params1, timeOut);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params1, timeOut);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params1);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = null;
JSONObject jsResp = null;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            String sServerResponse = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            Log.i("abc", "FROM: POST:" + sServerResponse);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: How to receive that image on server?Mean which MediaType should i use in REST API?

Comment: In this case the media type on the web service will be MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA

Answer (score 0):

I personally use loopj for client-server communication and images can be sent using files in it. Add the below dependency in your app gradle to use loopj

```
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

And then to send image

```
public void sendAllData() {
    String Url = "your url here";
    //If any auth is needed
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";

    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Media.DATA, Media.DATE_ADDED, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, Media.DATE_ADDED, null, "date_added ASC");
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToLast()) {
        Uri fileURI = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Media.DATA)));
        fileSrc = fileURI.toString();
        cursor.close();
    }

    // Bitmap compressedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.setBasicAuth(username, password);
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    try {
        params.put("pic", storeImage());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("MyApp", "File not found!!!" + fileSrc);
    }
    client.post(Url, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject responseBody) {
            //Do what's needed
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String errorResponse, Throwable error) {
            //Print error
        }
    });

}

private File storeImage() {
    String filename = "anyName";
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    OutputStream outStream = null;

    File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, filename + ".jpg");
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bookImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You implement a Service and post the image within it, please check my sample [here](https://github.com/MinaSamy/DailySelfie/blob/master/app/src/main/java/bloodstone/dailyselfie/android/utils/NetUtils.java)

Check the **postMultiPart** method.

Answer (score 0):

Change that to:
multipart/form-data

Comment: I want to show many images through imageview.For example i have an array of 10 indexes and in loop i want to show 10 images how can i do that.

Comment: You're having URLs in array?